# NextJs how to define page routes and api routes in a config file instead of folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am new to nextJs and the folder structure routing doesn't work for me and seems to obfuscate a lot of parameters. How can I create a standard API and routes config maybe in a .js file like regular routing libraries do?

The official documentation doesn't show how to do that.

Comment: You can't directly do that. you may need to use https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js

Comment: @VivekKJ from first glance, that seems even more complicated. can you point me to a working example

Comment: There should be a way to do this, IMO. The folder hierarchy is a gimmick that limits the flexibility of Nextjs.